# Android app to sort photos as in Lightroom desktop

Tags: lightroom, software-recommendation, android

I am searching for an android app that allows one to rank photos from a particular day or folder, say by giving a mark between 0 and 5, as in the desktop version of Adobe Lightroom. I haven't been able to find such an app yet.

It would for instance be very useful to sort photos from a given day to only keep the best ones and free up memory afterwards by removing all photos marked with a nil score.

I hope this is the good place to ask such a question.
Many thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lightroom for mobile. When you open image for editing on upper left corner you see text "Edit". Touch it and you will see in pulldown menu "Rate & Review" which is what you search for.

After rating go to All images and touching filter icon you will see the option to select only images with rate 5 (for example). Also touching three dots you can sort and group by day, week and so on.

Comment: That metadata is then neither embedded in the files, nor are sidecar files created, as far as I can tell. I assume Adobe keeps that inaccessible in your cloud account?